# PostgreSQL now() not returning time zone since DST started

Tags: sql, postgresql, pycharm, timestamp-with-timezone

I recently noticed that a column that records current timestamp (`now()`) had some records with no time zone (data type is `timestamp with time zone`). After investigating it further, it seems that `now()` has stopped returning time zone exactly since DST started (server time zone is AEST), which would be 1 October 2:00 AM. *i.e.* all records inserted before 1 October 2:00 AM have a time zone (`+10:00`) and everything after is without one.

Here's a query I just ran:

```
SELECT now(), localtimestamp, current_timestamp
```

Returns:

```
2017-11-20 12:02:23.232269  2017-11-20 12:02:23.232269  2017-11-20 12:02:23.232269
```

The database is running on an AWS RDS instance.

Comment: You should tell us a) which client you are using (`psql` being the gold standard), b) what `TimeZone` is set to.

Comment: Lots of people get confused about "Timestamp with time zone".. no time zone information is stored in that type of a column, however conversion to/from UTC is done automatically when data is inserted, changed, or queried.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe TimeZone is Australia/Melbourne (AEST as mentioned before). I used PyCharm to run the above query, but queries run on the server so I don't see why that matters?

Comment: @JoeLove That doesn't make sense. Before DST, all values were stored as UTC+10:00 (*e.g.,*  `2017-09-04 14:00:44.645158 +10:00`). Now, I only have local time stored (*e.g.,* `2017-11-22 02:42:52.094416`). These timestamps are created around midnight, so the latter is definitely AEST and not UTC. Also note the output of that query. All values are the same. No UTC conversion has been done for `now()`.

Comment: Additionally: the JDBC driver always changes the time zone to the client's timezone, so you will never see a value in the time zone of the server

Comment: Sorry that I didn't see the timezone in the question. The problem is most certainly related to PyCharm or the database driver it uses. You should add the code that you used to generate the output to the question.

Comment: Can you try converting to string or formatting or extracting the time zone in your request? That would make sure you get the information as the server has it. The output above might just be your client trying to be clever and only showing a timezone if it’s different from some reference timezone.

Comment: I found out what's happening! This is PyCharm's database tool being stupid (JDBC to be precise). Everything on the server is UTC (because server time zone is UTC). I tested with PSQL and SQLAlchemy. JDBC is converting to local time zone before returning query results.

Comment: @farshid I understand the confusion, but if you query dates, but if you set your client timezone to "America/Chicago" and run a query for a date PRIOR to DST and after DST you'll see two different offsets. Then change your clients timezone to "America/New_York" and you'll see different offsets-- the timezone is not stored, it's used to offset the data prior to storage or returning queries.